# ThreadLocalRandom setSeed

Tags: java, random, random-seed

Is it possible to provide a Seed to a [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html)?

It [looks like it isn't](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.java#L122).

```
/**
 * Throws {@code UnsupportedOperationException}.  Setting seeds in
 * this generator is not supported.
 *
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException always
 */
public void setSeed(long seed) {
    if (initialized)
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    rnd = (seed ^ multiplier) & mask;
}
```

So can we use `ThreadLocalRandom` using seed or it's not designed for that?

Comment: Why look at implementation when the public specification already gives you the answer? `Like the
global {@link java.util.Random} generator used by the {@link
java.lang.Math} class, a {@code ThreadLocalRandom} is initialized
with an internally generated seed that may not otherwise be
modified.`

Comment: yes, you are right. Should have read it more carefully.

Answer (score 14):

As @Marko Topolnik commented, `ThreadLocalRandom` does not allow to set your own seed.
You can bypass this problem by using a `ThreadLocal<Random>`, as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765399/should-i-prefer-threadlocalrandom-over-threadlocalrandom).

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @wscourge Ok thank you, I did not have enough reputation to comment but I had the same question and found the link useful in my case.

Comment: @wscourge No, it deserves to be a useful answer.